# Ubuntu stuck at plymouth boot splash

Tags: boot, plymouth, boot-failure

The title says it pretty much all. This is actually quite interesting. I set the timeout in grub2 to 0s. Now that Ubuntu does not boot, the grub menu appears.

I've tried booting in recovery mode, but then menus appear an I cannot use the keyboard.

When I choose to boot normally, the boot gets stuck at the plymouth boot splash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to fix it: Here is what I did.

In grub I choose *recovery mode*. I noticed that my file-exchange partition could not be mounted. Normally, during boot you can just skip the it then...

Here however, this was not possible: The error was, that for some reason the name of the file exchange partition was the same as the /home partition (/dev/sda5).

Therefore, I went into the **fstab** file and removed the entry for the file-exchange partition (which I did not edit manually, but with the program 'Storage Device Manager').

Now, everything works fine.